# Pool of processes in typescript

Tags: typescript, concurrency

I’m trying to implement a dispatcher that will perform long polling on AWS SQS and then dispatch (load balance) any message to n promises that will run in parallel. If I have more that n promises running I want to stop dispatching messages (for that I use AsyncGenerator) and I want to dispatch messages as soon as any of my promise pool finished.

I think I need some sort of blocking queue (like a buffer with max size and back pressure) that will be fed by my generator whilst my workers are taking elements for this buffer to treat them.

Note that order does not matter.

How can I implement those two processes so they can run concurrently?

If I’m not clear please tell me I’ll try to elaborate on your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I implement those two processes so they can run concurrently

You can spawn child processes to do tasks concurrently with  the built in `child_process` module.

## More

Specific examples are in the documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options